# pycharm error when running scripts with it

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to run scripts using pycharm and I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pytest
  File "/Users/maxwellflitton/Documents/oasis/github/OasisLMF/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import collect
  File "/Users/maxwellflitton/Documents/oasis/github/OasisLMF/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest/collect.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _pytest.deprecated import PYTEST_COLLECT_MODULE
  File "/Users/maxwellflitton/Documents/oasis/github/OasisLMF/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/deprecated.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _pytest.warning_types import PytestDeprecationWarning
  File "/Users/maxwellflitton/Documents/oasis/github/OasisLMF/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/warning_types.py", line 6, in <module>
    import attr
  File "/Users/maxwellflitton/Documents/oasis/github/OasisLMF/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/attr/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import converters, exceptions, filters, setters, validators
  File "/Users/maxwellflitton/Documents/oasis/github/OasisLMF/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/attr/converters.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._compat import PY2
  File "/Users/maxwellflitton/Documents/oasis/github/OasisLMF/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/attr/_compat.py", line 10, in <module>
    PYPY = platform.python_implementation() == "PyPy"
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'python_implementation'

Process finished with exit code 1

Empty suite
```

My initial thought was that there is a file in the oasislmf package with the same name as a file needed to run Python but I can't see anything like that in the stacktrace above. My Pycharm can run python scripts in other github projects with no problem so it must be project specific.

Comment: This `AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'python_implementation'` has nothing to do with PyCharm.

Comment: And, what is the script you are running! ?

Comment: @baduker turns out platform does have something to do with Pycharm, I changed the platform directory to something else and it worked

Comment: @kris the script doesn't matter you can see that the entire stack-trace is in the venv directory so it's to do with running python before we even hit the script

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out platform does have something to do with pycharm. I changed the platform directory to something else and it worked.